# How can a DSL gateway have an IP address outside of the router's network?

Tags: router, gateway, dsl

My friend has slow (about 1-2 Mbps) DSL service from Consolidated. They gave her a Comtrend 5372 modem/router. I logged in to the router and see these setting:

```
WAN Interface        pppoe_0_0_35
Link Type            DSL
Link Status          Up
Connection Type      PPPoE
WAN IP address       71.168.xxx.xxx
PPP Username         xxx@myfairpoint.net
Default Gateway      10.20.17.1
Primary DNS Server   64.222.xxx.xxx
Secondary DNS Server 64.222.xxx.xxx
```

I don't understand how the gateway can have an address like 10.20.17.1, which is a private address, not on the same segment as the router itself. Is this something magic about DSL?

Comment: Google CG-NAT and you'll understand.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks very much, never heard of that! If you'd like to write it as an answer, I'll accept it as the solution so you can earn some reputation points.

Comment: @GhanganAuto - This is not CGN as the WAN IP is globally routed.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Looks like davidgo is correct, as confirmed by the accepted answer from user1686

Comment: Indeed, I deleted mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, gateway addressing has nothing to do with CGNAT. Only the router's *own* address (which is still public in this case) would be affected by it, but the *gateway* IP address being private doesn't imply CGNAT in any way.

> I don't understand how the gateway can have an address like 10.20.17.1, which is a private address, not on the same segment as the router itself. Is this something magic about DSL?

Multiple IP networks can actually share a layer-2 segment, so an address being "not on the same IP subnet" does not imply "not on the same segment" at all. An address could be out-of-subnet but still on-link.

So although your gateway is on a different IP network, it can still be on the same L2 segment (and indeed *is* on the same segment, because if it weren't, you couldn't use it as a gateway).

(In addition, IP doesn't care about whether an address is private or not. There is no technical difference between the two, and it's valid to mix both kinds on the same network. Private addresses are only made special through IANA policy and ISP practices.)

But the actual "magic" is that it *doesn't really matter* whether a gateway is within your subnet or not. Any gateway address is possible as long as the OS knows how to map it to the corresponding layer-2 address (e.g. MAC address), as ultimately it's only the gateway's L2 address, not the IP address, that goes in packets.

So in the case of an out-of-subnet gateway, the OS just needs to be told to disregard the subnet mask and expect the address to be on-link (on-segment) regardless.

Doing so is not DSL-specific at all; although it is *more common* with DSL due to many ISPs using PPPoE – and that's a whole separate topic below – but it applies to any network type, and you could have the same configuration on standard Ethernet.

For example, having an off-subnet gateway is actually somewhat common on server datacenters (which might have dozens of disjoint public IP ranges on the same segment), and is very common on IPv6 (where auto-configuration always uses a private 'fe80:…' gateway address).

---

There's one more thing to note: in your case, there *is* no real "segment" as such. But this is nothing DSL-specific – it comes from the fact that your connection uses PPP.

Usually DSL is used in "Ethernet emulation" mode, in which case it works just like an Ethernet segment, with the DSL part being invisible to IP. But many ISPs choose to provide the IP service (the actual Internet access) not directly over that Ethernet, but through a PPP tunnel, PPPoE (PPP over Ethernet) in your case. (PPP itself isn't DSL-specific, either – it can go over a wide variety of transports.)

With PPP you have a *point-to-point* interface, which works rather differently from "broadcast" interfaces such as Ethernet. There is no layer-2 addressing on a PPP link (as there's only one possible layer-2 destination anyway), which means there's *no distinction* between addresses that are "on-link" or "same segment" and those which aren't.

In other words, your subnet mask and route gateways become mostly irrelevant when dealing with an PPP interface. (The gateway of a route is used to choose the layer-2 destination, e.g. Ethernet destination MAC, but there's no such thing in PPP.) As long as the packet is sent over the PPP interface, it'll get to the other end anyway.

This means the gateway address provided via PPP's configuration process is largely just for show, and it is not at all uncommon to see point-to-point links with mismatching host and gateway addressing. Indeed, because there's no distinction between on-link and off-link with PPP, the default route will work equally well even if it has *no* gateway at all.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks, I really needed it! And I appreciate that you explicitly debunked the comment about CG-NAT. I did google it, and read up on it, and thought to myself "it seems like this has to do with assigning the WAN IP address of the router". But in the end decided I just wasn't really understanding it.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing PPPoE (Point-to-Point Protocol over Ethernet) over DSL. The gateway is the PPP server. It is always on the same PPP link as your PPP client, simply by definition of what a PPP link is. Your UI isn't showing you the subnet mask for your WAN PPP link, but it's always 255.255.255.255 for PPP links, because point-to-point links always have exactly two hosts; the PPP client and the PPP server. Anything the PPP client transmits on the PPP link can only go to the PPP server, and vice-versa. So you don't need a broadcast address or a network address or room in the subnet for other host addresses, because it's not a multi-way shared link, it's a point-to-point link.

Comment: I think this is correct, and very succinct, thanks! But I'm marking the answer by @user1686 as the accepted one, because it provides more background information on networking basics, which I obviously sorely lack.

Answer (score 0):

The router has two network adapters, out-facing and inner-facing.
The purpose of the router is to be the bridge between the two,
to transfer packages from one interface to the other.

The inner one is in the local network created by the router, where
all devices have addresses in the form of `10.20.17.x, allocated by the router. The router has taken for itself the address of` 10.20.17.1`,
and it is the gateway to the world for all devices.

Your ISP has allocated this router the IP address of `71.168.xxx.xxx`,
on the ISP's network. All your devices will look to an outsider
as being the router, since externally the address of all of them
is `71.168.xxx.xxx`.

This is the short explanation about how it works, no magic involved.

Comment: In this case,  the router's DHCP is allocating LAN addresses in the 192.168.0.0/16 range. So your statement "The inner one is in the local network created by the router, where all devices have addresses in the form of 10.20.17.x, allocated by the router." is incorrect.  I think @user1686 has the best/most complete explanation.

Comment: The router is the DHCP server...

Comment: Yes, it is, that's what I meant when I said "the router's DHCP". Part of the router configuration is to set up DHCP, which includes specifying the range of IP addresses it should lease to clients. I think you inferred that because the gateway address was 10.20.17.1, then it's own address on the LAN was 10.20.17.1, so it must be handing out IP addresses in the CIDR range 10.20.17.0/24. But in fact the router's LAN address is 192.168.1.1, and its DHCP is configured to hand out addresses in CIDR range 192.168.1.0/24.

Comment: That's a detail. By handing out IP addresses, the router creates a functional inner network that can communicate with the outside world. If there was no DHCP server, the network would have still formed itself with local addresses, but been unable to go outside.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I don't get the point. All I'm saying is that the router's local address is 192.168.1.1, which is the gateway to the outside world for devices on its LAN - not 10.20.17.1 as you inferred. The accepted answer (as well as the other one by Spiff) notes that the gateway address is essentially irrelevant in a PPPoE connection such as this.

Comment: I think we agree about everything except the details: Three major elements - inner network, outer one, and router/bridge. user1686 thinks that everything is in the protocol, forgetting that the router is nothing more than a Linux computer, so everything we know about Linux is true here.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of what software is running on the router - it might be Linux or something else.. The router has the job of dealing with incoming packets on its WAN interface as well as its LAN interface (whether over ethernet or wireless), and sending them out over one interface/port or the other with appropriate modification depending on the protocol and its own configuration. Linux doesn't really have anything to do with it, does it? What specific characteristic(s) of Linux do you claim to be significant? It seems to me the one critical thing here is the PPPoE connection.

Comment: Many, *but not all*, DSL internet providers use PPPoE. Cable and fiber internet providers do not use it. Providers of other types of internet service such as fixed wireless internet may or may not use it. Any Linux computer can become a router, with or without PPPoE (the Raspberry Pi is often used here).

Comment: Thanks for the information. But as stated in the original question: "Connection Type      PPPoE"